# How to make a dropDownList in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

I have 2 attributes in model `jobs`, they are `tag` and `category`, I want to make a dropDownList that display the value of `tag` who have `category` equal 'salary', here is my code:

```
$s= CHtml::listData($model2, 'salary', 'tag');                         
echo CHtml::dropDownList('salary', 'salary', $s);
```

my db:

tag / category

1  /  val1

2  /  val1

a  /  val2

1000 / salary

2000 / salary

but I got a dropDownList that contains only the last value who have these conditions. what is the wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why you can get only one results, firstly the number of results you get in `$model2` affects the results, check if your are using `findAll` to return the all the rows matching a condition and not `find` and `findByPk` as they return only one value,

Secondly the second attribute of listData should be your value field 'salary' is not an attribute of the model, this has to be the valueField([see this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail)).

It will remain same if it assigned as `salary` - a constant value for all option elements, meaning your array will be overwritten for each reach leaving you with the array of one element containing the last value.

You should 'tag_id'/'id' or some sort of primary key from your model or tag value( assuming it is unique) to identify the tag by

```
$model2 = MyModel::model()->findAll("category = salary");
$s= CHtml::listData($model2, 'tag', 'tag');                         
echo CHtml::dropDownList('salary', 'salary', $s,array('empty'=>'--Select--'));
```

Comment: but `$model2` will be changed everytime due to the client conditions, at the first time `$model2` is initialized to `findAll()`, then it will be changed

Comment: hey see my revised answer, your problem is different than what i thgt, if you use already use findAll

Comment: I have changed `salary` to `category` which is the name of the model attribute that contain the value `salary`, the result is: I got for each value of `category` the last value of `tag` that match the `categoty`, i will show you my db in the question

Comment: It seems you don't have some sort of unique key , you can instead use the value of tag itself twice, as i have done now in my updated answer. See if that helps

Comment: this will return all the values of `tag`

Comment: your $model2 is where your data is found, all the records that satisfy model2 findAll condition will only show

Comment: ok now I added a column to db `idSalary`, it will put an id for each tag have cateogry salary, and the others will be null, when I used it instead of `salary` as a valueField, it returns all salaries and a non-salary value, at first, so the results are : united states, 1000$, 2000$, 3000$ ...why united states is appeared ??

Comment: most likely it is the placeholder/empty value, you can configure it in the fourth element of your `dropDownList` like this `CHtml::dropDownList('salary', 'salary', $s,array('empty'=>'--Select--'));`

Comment: the placeholder is exist